# Try and catch Error with Parse.com

Tags: parse-platform, swift2

I need some help with this:

```
func checkUserCredentials() -> Bool{
      PFUser.logInWithUsername(userName!, password: Contraseña!)
       if (PFUser.currentUser() != nil){
            return true
        }
        return false
   }
```

It says that PFUser.logInWithUsername(userName!, password: Contraseña!) has problems because its not marked with try ... and the error is not handled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
func checkUserCredentials() -> Bool{
    do {
        try PFUser.logInWithUsername(userName!, password: Contraseña!)
    } catch{
        // deal here with errors
    } 
    return PFUser.currentUser() != nil ? true : false
}
```

As it is quite basic issue I recommend you reading [some tutorials](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/new-syntax-swift-2-error-handling-try-catch)

Comment: if so, consider, marking it as an answer and optionally upvote (this is a small reward for me)

Comment: Note: no need to wrap the boolean condition with parenthesis in Swift.

Comment: Dealing with errors is up to the one having problem :) for the parenthesis, you are right, I just copied pasted his/her code, thanks for highlighting

Comment: Yeah, I've seen you updating your answer so I changed my comment (and upvoted for the good work). :)

Comment: I even made it shorter :)

Answer (score 1):

Just replace this

```
if (PFUser.currentUser() != nil) {
```

with

```
if let currentUser = try? PFUser.currentUser() {
```