# How to fix this try/guard error in swift

Tags: ios, swift

Trying to learn swift 2.0. Got this code, but it fails with the error can throw and error, not marked try and does not handle error. On line device.lock ...

```
func focusTo(value : Float) {
    if let device = captureDevice {
        if(device.lockForConfiguration()) {
            device.setFocusModeLockedWithLensPosition(value, completionHandler: { (time) -> Void in
                //
            })
            device.unlockForConfiguration()
        }
    }
}
```

Which I am sure is quite simple, but could somebody outline exactly how the syntax would look. Thinking I should use the swift "guard" instruction ideally and not try.

Comment: you need something similar to what I posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33039138/try-and-catch-error-with-parse-com/33039208#33039208)

Comment: *"Thinking I should use the swift "guard" instruction ideally and not try."* – No. Did you lookup the documentation of that method? *"In Swift, this method returns Void and is marked with the throws keyword to indicate that it throws an error in cases of failure. You call this method in a try expression and handle any errors in the catch clauses of a do statement, as described in ..."* +  a link to the relevant error handling documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**: `guard` only makes sure `device.lockForConfiguration()` doesn't return false. If it throws errors then it must be wrapped by `do - try - catch`:

In this case, `lockForConfiguration()` does not return `Bool`, so there's nothing to do with `guard`.

```
do {
    try device.lockForConfiguration()

    device.setFocusModeLockedWithLensPosition(...)
    device.unlockForConfiguration()

} catch let error as NSError {
    if error.code == 0 {
        print("Error code: 0")
    }
}
```

---

The syntax is:

```
guard device.lockForConfiguration() else {
    print("Lock configuration failed!!1")
    return
}

device.setFocusModeLockedWithLensPosition()
device.unlockForConfiguration()
```

You can even use it to replace `if`:

```
guard let device = captureDevice else {
    print("Device is nil!")
    return
}

// Do things with device
```

Comment: How does this work ? lockForConfiguration() throws error, how does a simple guard handle throwing behavior.

Comment: The first code block is wrong and does not even compile. `lockConfiguration()` instead of `lockForConfiguration()` is only a typo, but that method throws an error and must be called in a `try` expression.

Comment: Yes, I have focused on `guard` because OP wants to know what the syntax should be used. Edited for handling errors from the method.

Comment: What's issue exactly? I don't have any information about that `lockForConfiguration()` method. If it returns `Bool`, this should works fine.

Comment: Which SDK are you using? [lockForConfiguration()](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVCaptureDevice/lockForConfiguration:) does not return a value in Swift. Did you try to compile your code?

Comment: I just answer OP's question, I'm *not* using `lockForConfiguration()` in any of my code. I compiled my code but for another method, which return Bool. As in your link, it returns Void in Swift, so there's nothing to do with `guard` here. This code of OP `if(device.lockForConfiguration())` misleads me :)

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to answer a question asked by someone who does not realise their question is not correct. Look up XY Problem.

Comment: Thanks @Fogmeister, I've just looked for XY problem. Exactly this situation.